# Jquery cloning an input with label based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have an input file and I like the input styling and I cant get it without a label and ID

I spent couple of hours in it and I have solved it, I just want to know is there a better solution ?

```
          $("body").on("click",".btn-success",function(){
          $('.clone .custom-file-label').attr('class', 'custom-file-label')
          var html = $(".clone").html();
          var NewN = html.match(/id="(.*?)"/)[1];
          $('#' + NewN).attr("id", parseInt(NewN) + 1);
          $('.clone .custom-file-label').attr("for", parseInt(NewN) + 1);
          $(".increment").after(html);
      });

      $("body").on("click",".btn-danger",function(){
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jctrn2kh/1/

Answer (score 1):

1. I would decouple the logic from the DOM, for sure (e.g. not relying on the DOM for ID)
2. Put the template in the JS script, so I can modify the appearance and logic it uses easily
3. Would decrease the scope for reacting to clicks on dynamically created elements (e.g. not "body" but "container")
4. I would extract all CSS style to separate CSS

All of that in this snippet:

```js
// keeping track of IDs
let id = 1

// create item to be appended
const addFileInput = (id) => {
  // creating base node that will be returned
  const node = document.createElement('div')
  // setting classes on base node
  node.classList.add('custom-file', 'mb-3')
  // creating innerHTML of node
  node.innerHTML = `<input type="file" name="filename[]" id="${id}">
  <button class="btn btn-${id === 1 ? 'success' : 'danger'}" type="button">${id === 1 ? '+' : '-'}</button>
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="${id}">Choosse file</label>`
  // returning the node
  return node
}

// append the first input field (type: node)
const container = document.getElementById('field-container')
container.appendChild(addFileInput(id))

// functions for onClick
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(container).on("click", ".btn-success", function() {
    // incrementing the ID BEFORE appending
    container.appendChild(addFileInput(++id))
  });

  $(container).on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    // removing the exact element
    $(this).parents('.custom-file').remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.control-group .custom-file {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="field-container" class="control-group">
  <!-- will be filled out by JavaScript -->
</div>
```

This code may not seem simpler than yours, but it can be modified much easier

- the template created here is the basis, and if you modify that, everything will follow the modification
- the functions do not rely on any IDs - if you left them out, the clicks would still add and remove the items (OK, the labels and fields wouldn't fit together then)